# python creating stack operation class

Tags: python

I am new to Python language. i am trying to implement stack operation using classes and objects. This is the code  i have written till now:

```
class StackOperation:

    def __init__(self):
        front = 0
        MyStack = [None]*5

    def PushValue(self, value):
        MyStack[front] = value
        front += 1

    def PopValue(self):
        return MyStack[front -= 1]

    def PrintStack(self):
        for i in range(len(MyStack)):
            print MyStack[i]

stack = StackOperation()
stack.PushValue(10)
print stack.PopValue()
```

But this code gives me an error when i'm trying to run it. The error says:

"NameError: global name 'MyStack' is not defined"

I'm not sure what mistake i have made.
I would be great full if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyStack` and `front` are not instance variable that's why you can't access it. You have to make it instance variable using `self`.

```
class StackOperation:

    def __init__(self):
        self.front = 0
        self.MyStack = [None]*5

    def PushValue(self, value):
        self.MyStack[self.front] = value
        self.front += 1

    def PopValue(self):
        return self.MyStack[self.front]

    def PrintStack(self):
        for i in range(len(self.MyStack)):
            print self.MyStack[i]

stack = StackOperation()
stack.PushValue(10)
print stack.PopValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use them as `instance variable` but not `global variable` since they are all in the same class. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class StackOperation:

    def __init__(self):
        self.front = 0
        self.MyStack = [None]*5

    def PushValue(self, value):

        self.MyStack[self.front] = value
        self.front += 1

    def PopValue(self):
        return self.MyStack[self.front]

    def PrintStack(self):
        for i in range(len(self.MyStack)):
            print self.MyStack[i]

stack = StackOperation()
stack.PushValue(10)
print stack.PopValue()
```